# Uploading documents to elastic using curl or invoke-webrequest fails

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, curl, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to ingest data to my local elasticsearch cluster, I have the file sample-k8s-metrics.json.
According to the documentation I can upload the documents with

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -XPOST http://localhost:9200/sample-01/_bulk?pretty \
   --data-binary @sample-k8s-metrics.json
```

But I'm getting this error `Error extracting routing: source didn't contain any routing fields`

I also tried to use powershell invoke request

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:9200/sample-01/_bulk?pretty" -InFile "sample-k8s-metrics.json"  -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST
```

and I get exactly the same error

Any ideas where to look more here?
Thanks

I'm getting this error

```
    {
      "create" : {
        "_index" : "sample-01",
        "_id" : null,
        "status" : 400,
        "error" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Error extracting routing: source didn't contain any routing fields"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is an sample of the data:

```
{"create": {}}
{"@timestamp":"2022-06-20T23:59:40Z","kubernetes":{"host":"gke-apps-0","node":"gke-apps-0-0","pod":"gke-apps-0-0-0","container":{"cpu":{"usage":{"nanocores":62251,"core":{"ns":12828317850},"node":{"pct":2.77905e-05},"limit":{"pct":2.77905e-05}}},"memory":{"available":{"bytes":335503688},"usage":{"bytes":61401416,"node":{"pct":0.01770037710617187},"limit":{"pct":9.923134671484496e-05}},"workingset":{"bytes":693043},"rss":{"bytes":129761},"pagefaults":411638,"majorpagefaults":0},"start_time":"2021-03-30T07:59:06Z","name":"container-name-44"},"namespace":"namespace26"}}
```

full file can be found here:
https://static-www.elastic.co/v3/assets/bltefdd0b53724fa2ce/bltf2fe7a300c3c59f7/631b4bc5cc56115de2f58e8c/sample-k8s-metrics.json

Comment: can you show a sample of your `sample-k8s-metrics.json` file?

Comment: Here's a sample

https://static-www.elastic.co/v3/assets/bltefdd0b53724fa2ce/bltf2fe7a300c3c59f7/631b4bc5cc56115de2f58e8c/sample-k8s-metrics.json